# SQL query: how to distinct count of a column group by another column

Tags: sql, optimization, count

In my table I need to know if each `ID` has one and only one `ID_name`. How can I write such query?

I tried:

```
select ID, count(distinct ID_name) as count_name 
from table 
group by ID 
having count_name > 1
```

But it takes forever to run.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I should add that I'm not even sure if my query in the correct one since it never executed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  ID
from    YourTable
group by
        ID
having  count(distinct ID_name) > 1
```

or

```
select  *
from    YourTable yt1
where   exists
        (
        select  *
        from    YourTable yt2
        where   yt1.ID = yt2.ID
                and yt1.ID_Name <> yt2.ID_Name
        )
```

Now, most `ID` columns are defined as `primary key` and are unique.  So in a regular database you'd expect both queries to return an empty set.

Answer (score 0):

```
select tt.ID,max(tt.myRank) 
from
(
 select 
    ip.ID,ip.ID_name, 
    ROW_Number()  over (partition by ip.ID,ip.ID_nameorder by ip.ID) as myRank
 from YourTable ip
) tt
group by tt.ID
```

This gives you every ID with it's total number of ID_Name

If you want only those ID's which have more than one name associated just add a where clause
e.g.

```
select tt.ID,max(tt.myRank) 
from
(
select 
   ip.ID,ip.ID_name,
   ROW_NUMBER()  over (partition by ip.ID,ip.ID_nameorder by ip.ID) as myRank
from YourTable ip
) tt
**where tt.myRank > 1**
group by tt.ID
```